# Time duration Calculation in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I would like to calculate time duration of start request and end request for each iteration. I am able to get complete Test Execution time by using **beanshell** scripting as below:

```
long start = Long.parseLong(vars.get("TESTSTART.MS"))

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

log.info("Test duration: " + (end - start) / 1000 + " seconds");
```

But I want to calculate Time Duration for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [don't use Beanshell, from JMeter 3.1 you should be rather doing scripting in Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).

There are no [pre-defined variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) which reflect iteration start and end, you will need to calculate it yourself, i.e.

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) at the beginning of the Thread Group and put the following code into Script area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   vars.putObject('iterationStart', System.currentTimeMillis())
   ```
2. Similarly add a JSR223 Sampler to the end of the Thread Group and use the following code there:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   log.info('Iteration: ' + vars.get('__jm__' + ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + '__idx') + ' took ' + groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(vars.getObject('iterationStart'))))
   ```

Where:

- [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) - the JSR223 Samplers don't send their metrics to the Listeners hence they're not visible in the test results
- `ctx` - [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- `vars` - [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)